# VBA or Function to see if a serial number has been used

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-365

I have a workbook that contains the issued serial numbers for components. Column A has the serial number and Column B has the part number. I want to have a verification in column C if the serial number has been used already for the part number being entered in Column B. My best guess was to use a If/AND function to check if:

=IF(AND(B2:B100=B2,A2:A100=A2),"Used","Open")

My idea is that this will check column B if it matches B2 which is ASD01-1 and then check column A if it matches A2 which is 1. If both match the statement "Used" will be displayed. However the formula does not work. Any help on the matter would be appreciated.

Comment: Suggest using `COUNTIFS`

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad Your formula does not ensure that the `serial no/part no` combination are on the same row.  If I read the question correctly, that is what he wants.

Comment: @Ron Rosenfeld You are probably correct, `COUNTIFS` would be a better option

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to do it:

```
=IF(SUM((FILTER($A$2:$A2,$B$2:$B2=B2)=A2)*1)-1<>0,"Used","Open")
```

The `FILTER()` creates a list from the range of `this row` UP to the first row. So if in row 11, the ranges are A2:A11 and B2:B11. In other words, it will test everything ABOVE it for being values of interest. And the current row.

So those are TRUE/FALSE returns when compared to the serial # column's cell for this row. Multiplying them by 1 coerces them into being 1's and 0's. Notice the parentheses around the comparison expression so you are not multiplying the row's comparison value instead!

So now you have 1's and 0's and can `SUM()` them. Since the current row ALWAYS matches, you will always have a minimum of 1 returned. So, since that is a problem, subtract it away.

(You could do the range to operate on only a row higher up to the top, but... how do you handle the top row itself then? So while that sounds cleaner, this actually IS cleaner.)

So finally, you have a `SUM()` of either 0 (the serial # is open for use) or 1 (the serial number has been used once and is not open for use).

Note that you must have a rock solid practice of NEVER continuing on without first changing the offending serial # or you can have a variety of "third" outputs from `SUM()`:  things like 3 and 47, indicating this is the fourth or 48th use of the same serial number for a given part number. Even with that being true, you would still also know THIS particular row needs a new serial #, so it will not give false positives.

Well, it is not set to catch differences in upper case and lower case letters. To do so, you could change the references from simple ranges to `UNICODE(simple range or cell address)` forms so the Unicode values are compared, not the human characters. (You can do that any time, almost, when you have this issue. `UNICODE() is hugely useful that way. Also, use` UNICODE()`not`CODE()` as the latter is more for ASCII than anything else and reduces values higher than that set TO that set, so  you could have MANY unfortunate matches if you use any Unicode (non-ASCII) characters in your part numbers.)

But it is important to note, either way it would cause an issue for you, that part A12nnT8 and part A12nNT8 would show up the same in the formula at the start.

Answer (score 0):

You can't just compare a cell to a range like that. Your scenario is exactly why COUNTIFS exists.

COUNTIFS will count how many times Value1 appears in Range1, when Value2 also appears in Range2 *in the corresponding position* (ie the same row, for ranges next to each other, but they don't have to be neighbours, aligned or even in the same direction. If that count is more than 1, you have a duplicate.

Personally I would flag the duplicates as "Used" or whatever, but leave the unused/singletons blank to make it easier to spot the dupes a mile off (you could add conditional formatting to achieve a similar result, but why use 2 things when 1 alone will do?)

Cut to the chase careful with those dollar signs - the ranges need to stay fixed while the values in A2, B2 etc update as you go down the rows). In C2,enter this then copy down:

```
=IF(COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$100,$A2,$B$2:$B$100,$B2)>1,"Used","")
```